# Every real number lies between $N$ and $N+1$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I’m self-studying Tao’s *Analysis I* and following is a question from it.

> *Exercise 5.4.3.* Show that for every real number $x$ there is exactly one integer $N$ such that $N ≤ x < N +1$. (This integer $N$ is called the integer part of $x$, and is sometimes denoted $N = ⌊x⌋$.)

Uniqueness is easy to show.

I wish to know if my following proof idea for existence is correct. It’d suffice to show this for positive real numbers.

Suppose on the contrary that there existed a positive real number $x$ such that for all positive integers $N$, $x<N+1$ implies $x<N$. Since there exists a positive integer $N_0$ such that $x<N_0=M+1$, where $M=N_0-1<N_0$ is a non-negative integer, and hence, $x<M$. Since $x$ is positive, $M$ is also positive. Hence we have shown that for all positive integers $N_0$, $x<N_0$ implies $x<M$ for some positive integer $M<N_0$, contradicting the principle of infinite descent, since I can create an infinitely descending list of positive integers $n$ satisfying the property $x<n$. Hence the proof completed.

Comment: You reach a contradiction when the "descent" gets to $0$. You know $x< N_0$ but that doesn't mean the $N_0$ is the one you are looking for. You deduce $x< n$ for every $n\le N$ but $x$ could be a number $0<x<1$ so you need to take the extra step $x<0$ to get a contradiction with "$x$ is positive"

Comment: @Pedro I’m not trying to get a contradiction with “$x$ is positive.”

Comment: Then I'm not convinced by your proof. I don't see where you reach a contradiction

Comment: @Pedro See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent. It is also used by Tao in proving that $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational number.

Comment: Also see https://www.cut-the-knot.org/WhatIs/WhatIsInfiniteDescent.shtml.

Comment: I know what infinite descent is. Maybe you want to specify that the $N_0$ you use is the _least_ positive integer greater than $x$ and then get the contradiction by finding an $M$ smaller than $N_0$

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to add some to your proof. As you said let's take $x$ positive. You claim that there exist an integer $N_0 > x$ and this is true (natural number are infinite). Now, by contradiction, since $x<N_0$ we have two cases:

(1) If $N_0=0$, you have a contradiction because $x$ is positive;

(2) If $N_0>0$, then you have $x<N_0-1$ and you can iterate the procedure until you arrive at the case (1) (infinite discent)

Now your proof is completed.

**Another approach:**

I propose also a more linear approach (in my opinion). Let's take $x$ positive and $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,...\}$. Consider the set 
\begin{equation}
S=\{n\in \mathbb{N} \ | \ x < n+1\}
\end{equation}
Since $S$ is non empty (natural numbers are infinity), thanks to minimum principle exist the minimum $N\in \mathbb{N}$ of $S$.

Now $x< N+1$ because $N\in S$ and $N\leq x$ because is the minimum of $S$. So 
$$
N\leq x< N+1
$$

Comment: "You claim that there exist an integer $N_0>x$ and this is true (natural number are infinite)." That there is such $N_0$ follows from the continuity axiom or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to use a basic property of the real numbers:  given any real number, x, there exist an integer, N, such that N> x and conversely, given any integer N there exist a real number, x, such that x> N.